# Are school cards haram?

Tags: sunni, gambling, school

Aslam o Alakom to whom ever is reading this, So some further context: My school hands out cards to people who do good deeds or portray good character traits. You can redeem cards by putting it in a raffel, at the end of the week whoever wins the rafel wins a gift card or candy. Is it haram for me to participate in this?

Comment: Please clarify what is the gambling part here, when no money is involved?

Answer (score -1):

**Wa 3laykum As Salaam,**

I hope you are doing well. With regards to just cards there is nothing inherently wrong with as they are not religious nor pertain to any non-Islamic belief.

And as long as you dont use money to purchase the raffle then it should be permissible.

**References :**
https://islamqa.org/hanafi/daruliftaa/7749/fiqh-of-gambling/

https://islamqa.info/en/answers/147826/ruling-on-playing-some-electronic-games-with-the-intention-of-winning-a-prize-without-spending-any-money

https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/99451/winning-money-prizes-without-participating-with-any-money

ALLAH (Glory Be To HIM) Knows Best

Comment: The question nowhere mentioned money so how could this raffle be a lottery or be haram!

Comment: As Salaamu 3laykum, jazakaALLAH Khairan. I have changed my answer after learning more about that.